# Chrome extensions : How to know when a tab has finished loading, from the background page

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using a listener in the background page to know when a tab is loaded:

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId) { })
```

But the listener is fired twice: when the page has started loading, and when the page has finished.Is there a way to differentiate the two cases?

Comment: To know when a tab **starts** loading, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191679/chrome-extension-inject-js-before-page-load/19192010#19192010

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Luckily have found the solution.

There is an [additional parameter](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) that holds the status value:

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId , info) {
  if (info.status === 'complete') {
    // your code ...
  }
});
```

Status can be either `loading` or `complete`.

Comment: Isn't ); missing at the end?

Comment: PS Note this is good for background scripts.  For content scripts, just use `window.onready`

Comment: @PeterEhrlich Problem with Window.onready is that it fires up as soon as init DOM is loaded. If you try for sites like gmail which keeps getting data, it fires immediately.

Comment: How to know exactly which tab finished, as the info has just status completed. if user opened 3 tags one after other, theres no way of knowing which one actually finished first and which one last. @Balthazar

Comment: I did it this way, but doesn't work for youtube. The site is still incomplete when trying to find elements.

Comment: @SoumyajitDutta the tabId parameter should help you here, to distinguish. using this param you can get the url of that tab

Answer (score 32):

I wanted a easier way to do this after opening a tab

```
function createTab (url) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        chrome.tabs.create({url}, async tab => {
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function listener (tabId, info) {
                if (info.status === 'complete' && tabId === tab.id) {
                    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(listener);
                    resolve(tab);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

so it would be

```
let tab = await createTab('http://google.com');
```